# Coloring Minecraft Items Without Mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how you might be able to change the colour(s) of an item, without using mods in Minecraft? Is there a way I can use commands to do this?

Comment: This is great that you want to share your knowledge with others. As I’m sure you are aware, StackExchange is for asking questions, and so this type of post would be considered inappropriate. The correct thing to do would be to answer your own question. You can do this either when composing a question by ticking a box that says ‘answer your question’ or with the answer button here.

Comment: I understand; will do as you have advised next time. Thank you!

Comment: @tegopole I have re-worded your post into a question, then posted your original "question" as an answer. please feel free to copy and paste it as your own answer if you want to - I will delete my post if/when you do (don't want to steal your hard earned work as my own:D)

Answer (score 0):

(Self-answer from [tegopole](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/255052/tegopole)):

I thought I'd help out others searching for a way to change an item's color without using mods (since I don't have enough reputation to answer those threads).

After experimentation in 1.16.2, I found that the code:

```
ITEMNAME{display:{Name:'{"text": "NAME", "color": "COLORNAME"}'}}
```

Color names:

- blue
- dark_blue
- green
- dark_green
- red
- dark_red
- yellow
- gold
- aqua
- dark_aqua
- light_purple
- dark_purple
- white
- gray
- dark_gray
- black